# CRM 2011 Plugin (C#) - Iterate over records in form sub-grid

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to write a plugin that iterates over a bunch of records inside a forms sub-grid.  Previously the plugin checked a single lookup and performed some basic functions based on the value it held.  Now the client wants multiple records to be linked to this record in an N:N relationship.  I've seen this can be done in JavaScript but unfortunately this is no use to me.  Can this be done in a plugin?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done; and some methods of doing this are easier than others.  As you noticed, the 1:N relationship is easy to manage from the child side through an EntityReference to the parent.

In the N:N relationship, you can retrieve the related entity using an approach like the one suggested in this article (not mine) about [Retrieving Relationships](http://mscrmkb.blogspot.com/2010/12/crm-2011-retrieve-related-entity-data.html)

Another approach (depending on how you generated your code with the CrmSvcUtil):
`<entity>.GetRelatedEntities<<related entity type>>("<Relationship Name>", null);`

Answer (score 1):

If the records inside the sub grid are linked with the main entity record, by having its GUID as parent ID, then you could use QueryExpression/QueryByAttribute to retrieve all the records in your subgrid and then iterate over them...